# Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted in cakephp\src\ORM\TableRegistry.php in Cakephp 4x

Tags: memory-leaks, out-of-memory, query-builder, cakephp-4.x

I have write a simple query which will fetch maximum 5 records,My query structure is like
$userSettingsTable->find()->where(['user_id' => 2])->first()->toArray();

This is showing as Memory limit exhausted

I have also set  ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
Still issue is not resolved.
Please help me

Comment: This seems almost certain to be a problem not related to the query itself. If you remove all the code around it and just leave the query, does it still blow up? If so, can you [enable SQL logging](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/database-basics.html#query-logging) and show us what that one line of code generates as a query to the database?